# Reorder list such that, as much as possible, the sum of all previous numbers is less than the current number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have come across a problem which is as follows, There are cars inside a parking lot, each driver takes a specific amount to park their car, a driver will get unhappy if the time he has to wait is more than the time he takes to park the car, which means the drivers which are ahead of him in the line in total take more time to park their cars. I want to find a sequence which minimizes the drivers in the line. For example:
2 15 1 5 3 --> is the sequence of drivers in the line. The first driver obviously will be happy since they dont have to wait for anyone, the second one in the line (15) takes 15 minutes to park but only has to wait for 2 minutes so he will be happy too, problem starts from the third driver and so on. I want to rearrange them so the number of unhappy drivers is minimized. I have come up with a solution which finds all the permutations of the items in the list and finds the unhappy drivers for each one of them but it seems to be very slow when the number of drivers are increased by a huge amount. My code is

```
import itertools
driverList = input().split()
for i in range(len(driverList)):
    driverList[i] = int(driverList[i])


permutationList = []
permutationList += list(itertools.permutations(driverList))

maxCount = 1
for i in range(len(permutationList)):
    count = 1
    sumCount = permutationList[i][0]
    for j in range(1, len(permutationList[i])):
        if permutationList[i][j] > sumCount:
            count += 1
        sumCount += permutationList[i][j]
    if count > maxCount:
        maxCount = count

print(maxCount)
```

Is there any other way or data structure I can make use of to make this algorithm much more efficient. Thank you very much.
The answer for the input of "2 15 1 5 3" will be 4, this answer is given cause if the cars are rearranged in the sequence of "1 3 5 2 15" the number of happy drivers will be 4.

- 1 > 0 (happy)
- 3 > 1 (happy)
- 5 > 3+1 (happy)
- 2 < 5+3+1 (unhappy)
- 15 > 2+5+3+1 (happy)

Comment: This question isn't completely clear, either from the title or the description. By combining them, I can *guess* what you want, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: The code uses the sum of *all* the preceding numbers, not just the previous 2. Is this correct? Also, you should explain why simply sorting the numbers doesn't produce the output you want.

Comment: Hey, yes that's correct. I have edited the question by giving an example.

Comment: Okay ... so, if you just sorted, you have: `1 happy`, `2 happy`, `3 maybehappy`, `5 unhappy`, `15 unhappy` ... where `maybehappy` means "if you changed `>` to `>=`" ... but if it was changed to 2.5 or something it would still be unhappy. So you're certain to get some unhappy drivers ... basically, the optimal solution is: always start with the smallest remaining number that won't be unhappy, then stick all the always-unhappy ones at the end.

Comment: sort the numbers in ascending order and check if total sum before a element is greater than that element if it is that means he is is unhappy and so all the element after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't proved this correct, but I can't think of any counterexamples, and it *is* efficient. Note many style improvements over your original code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def happiest_drivers(drivers):
    drivers = sorted(drivers)
    assert drivers and drivers[0] > 0
    rv = []
    wait = 0
    # First, repeatedly find the fastest driver who will be happy.
    for i, d in enumerate(drivers):
        if d > wait: # or >= if that makes more sense
            rv.append(d)
            drivers[i] = 0
            wait += d
    num_happy = len(rv)
    # Then add all the unhappy drivers. There's nothing we can do about them.
    for d in drivers:
        if d:
            rv.append(d)
    return rv, num_happy

def main():
    order, num_happy = happiest_drivers([int(x) for x in input().split()])
    print('%d/%d happy with order %r' % (num_happy, len(order), order))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using one for loop:

```
import random

# set num drivers
NUM_DRIVERS = 5
# set max wait time
MAX_WAIT_TIME = 20

# create driver parking list - max out at 20 min parking job
parking = [random.randint(1, MAX_WAIT_TIME) for _ in range(NUM_DRIVERS)]

parking
# [20, 16, 4, 4, 2]

def happy_drivers(parking_list):
    """
    happy_drivers takes an input list and returns a custom ordered 
    list of driver wait times before they become unhappy. 

    Each item in the list contains the maximum amount of time 
    a driver is willing to wait to park a vehicle before they become
    unhappy. Additionally, this wait time also corresponds to how long it 
    takes them to park a vehicle. 

    Take an input list [20, 10, 4, 4, 2]. An optimal happy ordering 
    could be parking cars in [2, 4, 10, 20, 4] where there are 4 happy drivers. 
    If the drivers were simply sorted, i.e. [2, 4, 4, 10, 20], 
    there would only be 2 happy drivers. 

    Parameters
    -----
    parking_list - list
        Input list of maximum wait times per driver

    Returns
    -----
    new_driver_list - list
        Sorted driver list based on creating the fewest unhappy
        drivers

    happy_driver_idx - int
        Number of happy drivers who didn't have to wait longer
        than their max wait time
    """
    # sort parking
    sorted_parking = sorted(parking_list)
    cur_wait = 0
    new_driver_list = []
    happy_driver_idx = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(sorted_parking):
        if item > cur_wait:
            cur_wait += item
            new_driver_list.insert(happy_driver_idx, item)
            happy_driver_idx += 1
        else:
            new_driver_list.append(item)

    return new_driver_list, happy_driver_idx

optimal_ordering, happy_drivers = happy_drivers(parking)
print("""An optimal ordering: {}\nNum happy drivers: 
     {}""".format(optimal_ordering, happy_drivers))

# An optimal ordering: [2, 4, 16, 4, 20]
# Num happy drivers: 3
```

Comment: Is that not this part? # An optimal ordering: [2, 4, 16, 4, 20]
# Num happy drivers: 3; If I missed something please let me know and I will update it

Comment: ahhh I see, in the documentation - will change, thank you both.

Comment: @user3386109 seriously is, I think I got it now

Comment: `.insert()` is `O(n)` since it has an extra `for` loop hidden inside, making this `O(n²)` overall. My answer is `O(n + n)` which reduces to just `O(n)`

Comment: @o11c your answer calls `sorted` which is `O(nlogn)` thus your algorithm will not run in linear time. Don't you think so?

Answer (score -2):

Simply Use list.sort() function to arrange the numbers in ascending/descending order. For more information help(list.sort()) in your ipython notebook

Comment: does not work:  `[1,2,2,2,4,10]` => `[waiting: 0,1,3,5,9]` == only first 2 are happy. By reordering to `[1,2,4,10,2,2]` you get `[waitting: 0,1,3,7,17,19]` --> 4 happy customers.